# Write a polynomial equation of the smallest degree with roots $3$, $4i$, and $-4i$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I already have the answer to this question (it's an example). However, I am still confused with steps 2-3. How does $x^2+4ix-4ix-16i^2$ simplify to $x^2-16$?

1. $(x-3)(x-4i)(x+4i)=0$
2. $(x-3)(x^2+4ix-4ix-16i^2)=0$
3. $(x-3)(x^2+16)=0$
4. $x^3+16x-3x^2-48=0$
5. $f(x)=x^3-3x^2+16x-48$

Comment: In step (2), $4i \times -4i = -16\times i^2 = 16$, not $-16x^2$

Comment: Your edit is still not correct going from (2) to (3), you wrote $-16 \times i^2 = -16$ (which is incorrect), where it should be $i^2 = -1$

Comment: Your work is correct now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first mistake is in step 2. It should read

$$(x-3)(x^2+4ix-4ix-16i^2)=0$$

Note that I removed the $x$ from the last term. With that change, the progression to step 3 should be clear: the $+4ix$ cancels with the $-4ix$, and $i^2$ is replaced with $-1$.

There also should be a change in step 3, changing the $-16$ with a $+16$. You should be able to continue from there, changing the appropriate signs.

Comment: Oh sorry, that was a typo error by myself. So why does step 3 not include an "i" next to 16? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JoshuaLajoie There's no $i$, there's only $i^2$. And $i^2$ is know to be equal to.... ___

Comment: @JoshuaLajoie: Because the $i^2$ was replaced with $-1$, so $-16i^2$ is replaced with $+16$. That is, after all, the very definition of $i$!

Comment: @RoryDaulton, Ahh okay, I completely forgot about that. Thanks, this helps a ton!

Answer (score 1):

> How does $(x^2+4ix-4ix-16ix^2)$ simplify to $(x^2-16)$?

It doesn't. There would be an $i^2 \equiv -1$ there, which would turn it to $x^2+16$. Rest follows in the manner you are going ahead with.